# Certora: When to define a rule vs an invariant?

Tags: certora

According to the Certora docs:

```
Rules: A rule describes the expected behavior of the methods of a contract.

Invariants: Invariants describe facts about the state of a contract that should always be true.
```

With these definitions, one could argue all rules *are* invariants. When does it make sense to use one vs the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule is not an invariant because it does not prove that a property always holds. It proves that in a certain situation, the property holds. They are close so I understand the confusion. Here's how I think about it:

You can almost implement an invariant as a rule by first requiring the property, calling an arbitrary method, and then asserting it. The missing part here is that with an invariant the property is checked after the constructor, which is what lets you assume it afterwards. Without a check on the constructor, we can not prove that a property always holds because the initial assumption is unbacked. See [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)

Here's a general example with some specific points:

An invariant "X" must satisfy:

a) "The constructor establishes X"

b) "When we start in a state that fulfills X and run any of the methods, we end up in X"

Rules are more free-form.

```
rule myRule {
   require X;
   foo();
   assert Y;
}
```

Here, `myRule` says "when we start in a state that fulfills X and execute `foo`, then we end up in a state that fulfills Y".

Clearly, the b)-part of an invariant can be written like this, but one can do many more things, like many calls, or reset the state in the middle and compare the effects of two calls, and much more.